# React Navigation reset with params doesn't work

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

On successful login, I want to redirect the user to home page and pass their user id as a parameter. The Home page is in a different navigator so I am calling it like this ->

```
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      key: null,
      actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({
          routeName: 'drawerStack',
          params: { user }
        })
      ]
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

It redirects me to the right page and doesn't allow me to go back to login page (which is what I want). However, the params are not being passed to the new page. Trying to access params shows "undefined" in the console.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    user: this.props.navigation.state.params.user,
  };
}
```

I am using [expo](http://expo.io) so the console output is showing me some useful information such as...

```
New State:  Object {
  "index": 0,
  "routes": Array [
    Object {
      "index": 0,
      "key": "id-1508503071251-9",
      "params": Object {
        "user": "OvoJQFvzy7UBKF3iif9onujRbV43",
      },
...
```

But I don't know how I can access that user param.

Comment: Where exactly do you have this line? `const params = props.navigation.state.params || {};`

Comment: @RamiEnbashi I have removed this line while trying new things but at the moment I have a line in my constructor essentially trying to do the same thing... this.state = {
      user: this.props.navigation.state.params.user,
    };. Ive updated my question.